# Jmockit Missing invocation to mocked type at this point

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4, jmockit

I am new to Jmockit and  I have a scenario to mock the List which is being used in the
Business logic. When I used the below implementation I get the **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing invocation to mocked type at this point; please make sure such invocations appear only after the declaration of a suitable mock field or parameter**

Please find my implementation below.

```
package com.example.logic;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EmployeeDao {

    public boolean validate() {
        List<String> list = getList();
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        //actual logic for getting the data 
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        return list;
    }
}
```

## Test

```
package com.example.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.example.logic.EmployeeDao;

import mockit.NonStrictExpectations;

public class EmployeeDaoTest {
    @Test
    public void testEmployeeDaoTest() {
        EmployeeDao employeeDao = new EmployeeDao();
        new NonStrictExpectations() {
            {
                employeeDao.getList();
                // returns("A", "B");
                //times = 1;
                result = getMockList();
                //returns("A", "B");
            }

        };
        assertTrue(employeeDao.validate());
    }

    private List<String> getMockList() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("A");
        return list;
    }
}
```

When I run the above Test class I got the below error. But intead of instanitiating the  EmployeeDao, if the @Mocked annotation is being used, then I will get only
assertion error

```
@Mocked
EmployeeDao employeeDao;
```

After few research over I have comeacross another way of mocking the method by using MockUp. But due to some reasons, I dont want to use. It would be helpful
if this could be ressolved with the above approach which I have written. Just would like to know whats wrong with the above implementation.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing invocation to mocked type at this point; please make sure such invocations appear only after the declaration of a suitable mock field or parameter
    at com.example.test.EmployeeDaoTest$1.<init>(EmployeeDaoTest.java:23)
    at com.example.test.EmployeeDaoTest.testEmployeeDaoTest(EmployeeDaoTest.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Just curious, did either of these answers help you solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that you need to use [partial mocking](http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Mocking.html#partial) (because you are testing a class and mocking one of its methods).

The way of doing it is like this:

```
@Test
public void testEmployeeDaoTest() {
    EmployeeDao employeeDao = new EmployeeDao();
    new NonStrictExpectations(employeeDao) {
        {
            employeeDao.getList();
            // returns("A", "B");
            //times = 1;
            result = getMockList();
            //returns("A", "B");
        }

    };
    assertTrue(employeeDao.validate());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- the `NonStrictExpectations` class was removed in v1.25.  The current
  version is v1.39.  You might want to upgrade and get the benefit of all the latest fixes and enhancements
- the first example above didn't mock anything, and adding the @Mocked annotation mocks every instance of the `EmployeeDao`, which in effect means you wouldn't be testing anything.

The middle ground is a partial mock, which would mock only select method of a class or instance.  I've modified the example to use a regular `Expectations` instance with `minTimes = 0` (making it optional), and simplified the result for IMHO a more readable test:

```
@Test
public void testEmployeeDaoTest() {
    EmployeeDao employeeDao = new EmployeeDao();
    new Expectations(EmployeeDao.class) {
        {
            employeeDao.getList();
            result = Collections.singletonList("A");
            minTimes = 0;
        }

    };
    assertTrue(employeeDao.validate());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create mockup of getlist() method and return required object based on test case

```
 new MockUp<EmployeeDao>() {

                @Mock
               List<String> getList() // no access modifier required
                {
                    return requiredListOutput;
                }
    }
     new Expectations() {

                {

            };

     assertTrue(employeeDao.validate());//required assertions
```